# I tried to convert str into an int, but I still can't get the number I need for comparison

Tags: python, list, dictionary, types

I tried to convert `str` into an `int`,
but I still can't get the number I need for comparison.

I am referring to the very first function - `highest_bid()` on the line

```
    old_player = bidder_list["Bid"]
```

Full code:

```
from replit import clear
bidder_list = []

bidding_finished = True

def highest_bid(bidder_list):
  for bidder in bidder_list:
    new_player = 0
    old_player = bidder_list["Bid"]
    old_player = int(old_player)
    if new_player < old_player:
      new_player = old_player
    
  print(bidder_list)
  print(new_player)

while bidding_finished: 
  bidder = input("What is your name? \n")
  bid = input("How much are you willing to pay?  \n$")
  continue_bid = input("Are you the last bidder? Yes or No? \n").lower()

  def auction(bidder, bid): 
    bidder_list.append({"Bidder": bidder, "Bid": bid})  

  auction(bidder = bidder, bid = bid) 
  
  clear()

  if continue_bid == "No" or continue_bid == "n":
     bidding_finished = False
     highest_bid(bidder_list)
     print(bidder_list)
     print("Bidding Finished! The Winner will always be Percy.")
```

Comment: bidder_list is a list. You cannot index that with a string ("Bid" in your example)

Comment: Thanks anyway! I am so new to Python and everything about computer languages...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
auction(bidder = bidder, bid = bid)
```

to be

```
auction(bidder = bidder, bid = int(bid))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `continue_bid == "No"` to `continue_bid == "no"` since you convert the input to all lowercase.

When you cast old_player to an integer here:

```
old_player = bidder_list["Bid"]
old_player = int(old_player)
```

is fine.

However,

```
def auction(bidder, bid): 
bidder_list.append({"Bidder": bidder, "Bid": bid})
```

Here, you are creating a list that contains a dictionary. You can't index the list by doing

`old_player = bidder_list["Bid"]`

You need to dereference the list and then go to the dictionary like:

`old_player = bidder_list[0]["Bid"]`

Since you are iterating over the entire bidder_list as bidder for each index,

you can do this instead:

```
def highest_bid(bidder_list):
  for bidder in bidder_list:
    new_player = 0
    old_player = bidder["Bid"]
    old_player = int(old_player)
    print(f'value: {old_player}  type: {type(old_player)}')
    if new_player < old_player:
      new_player = old_player
    
  print(bidder_list)
  print(new_player)
```